# Mockito: Verifying with generic parameters

Tags: java, generics, parameters, verification, mockito

With Mockito I can do the following:

```
verify(someService).process(any(Person.class));
```

But how do I write this if `process` takes a `Collection<Person>` instead? Can't figure out how to write it correctly. Just getting syntax errors...

Answer (score 111, accepted):

Try:

```
verify(someService).process(ArgumentMatchers.<Collection<Person>>any());
```

Actually, IntelliJ automatically suggested this fix when I typed `any()`... Unfortunately you cannot use static import in this case.

Comment: Thanks it works... but God it looks horrible, there have to be a nicer way to right that...

Comment: Thumbs up on the only solution that answers the question as stated as opposed to targeting the special case of matching containers.

Comment: This answer is now incorrect. The answer below gives a better solution.

Comment: I may be mistaken but I do not think this is the correct answer. 
Although it removes the warning, the verification switches from 
"any(Collection.class)" to any(), which does not verify anything. At least before there was a class check. Isn't it?

Comment: How did you get intellij to automatically suggest that to you?

Comment: `Matchers` is deprecated, should now use `ArgumentMatchers`.

Answer (score 27):

Try :

```
verify(someService).process(anyCollectionOf(Person.class));
```

Since version [1.8](https://github.com/mockito/mockito/blob/1.8.0/src/org/mockito/Matchers.java) Mockito introduces

```
public static <T> Collection<T> anyCollectionOf(Class<T> clazz);
```

Comment: For others who come to this and need it, there's also an anyListOf() in addition to anyCollectionOf(), see: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10512526/908677

Comment: anyCollectionOf(Class<T> clazz) will be removed in Mockito 3.0 and java8. There will be a new method: anyOptional(Class<T> class) see: https://github.com/mockito/mockito/issues/308

Answer (score 1):

if you use a own method, you can even use static import:

```
private Collection<Person> anyPersonCollection() {
    return any();
}
```

Then you can use

```
verify(someService).process(anyPersonCollection());
```

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to the accepted answer you can try:

```
verify(someService).process(Mockito.<SomeGenericClass<Person>>any());
```

Where I used `org.mockito.Mockito` instead of `Matchers`.

Answer (score -1):

You can't express this because of type erasure. Even if you could express it in code, Mockito had no chance to check it at runtime. You could create an interface like

```
interface PersonCollection extends Collection<Person> { /* nothing */ }
```

instead and use this throughout your code.

Edit: I was wrong, Mockito has [anyCollectionOf(..)](http://docs.mockito.googlecode.com/hg/org/mockito/Matchers.html#anyCollectionOf%28java.lang.Class%29) which is what you want.

Comment: Actually, it *could* be expressed with a "type literal" object if the API accepted it: `any(new TypeLiteral<Collection<Person>>() {})`. Not pretty, of course, but it does work since all the type information is available at runtime (through Reflection or a bytecode library).

Comment: @Rogerio: you are right, and it seems Mockito indeed supports this now. Haven't used it in a while...