# How to use Mockito's anyCollectionOf()

Tags: generics, mockito

An answewr on this thread suggested using anyCollectionOf() however I cannot get it to work
[Mockito: Verifying with generic parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6175753/mockito-verifying-with-generic-parameters)

I have a Generic Class for holding two "versions" of the same object for comparison purposes

```
public class ChangedVO<T> {

private T before;
private T after;

/*** Constructors ***/

public ChangedVO() {}

public ChangedVO(T before, T after) {
    this.before = before;
    this.after = after;
}

/*** Getters & setters ***/

...
}
```

Now in my UnitTest the following code "does" work...

```
verify(emailService, never()).sendBookChangesEmail(Matchers.<List<ChangedVO<BookVO>>>any());
```

...however I'm interested to know how the same thing can be achieved using anyCollectionOf() ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Interesting use of Mockito with generics. The only way I think you can use `anyListOf()` in this situation is by typing

```
verify(emailService, never()).sendBookChangesEmail(anyListOf((Class<ChangedV0<BookV0>>) null));
```

Instead of passing a class instance you pass it null. This is not how the documentation says you shoud use `anyListOf()` but in this specific situation it seems to work.

The problem is generic type erasure in Java which makes that you can not differentiate between an instance of

```
Class<ChangedV0<BookVO>> or
Class<ChangedV0>
```

during runtime and therefore there is no way you can create anything that statically conforms to

```
Class<ChangedV0<BookVO>>
```

Comment: Thanks for your feedback fiv. I prefer your solution to the Matchers one that I proposed. It reads better.