# Mockito: List Matchers with generics

Tags: java, generics, warnings, mockito, matcher

Mockito offers:

```
when(mock.process(Matchers.any(List.class)));
```

How to avoid warning if `process` takes a `List<Bar>` instead?

Answer (score 326, accepted):

For Java 8 and above, it's easy:

```
when(mock.process(Matchers.anyList()));
```

For Java 7 and below, the compiler needs a bit of help. Use `anyListOf(Class<T> clazz)`:

```
when(mock.process(Matchers.anyListOf(Bar.class)));
```

Comment: Note: this is deprecated in Mockito 2.* and will be removed in Mockito 3. Deprecated because Java 8 compiler can infer the type now.

Comment: @artbristol do you know if with anySet() should work as same as anyList()? I am in Java 8 and a warning is thrown in Eclipse IDE

Comment: Better to use `anyListOf`. Even though `anyList` works, it emits a warning.

Comment: `anyListOf` is deprecated, so it is better NOT to use it.
Example for Java 8 doesn't work in case of method overload, for example if you have a method accepting 2 different lists: `List<DBEntity>` and `List<DTO>`
I've solved this problem using `ArgumentMatchers` with generic: `when(adapter.adapt(ArgumentMatchers.<DTO>anyList())).thenCallRealMethod();`

Answer (score 27):

In addition to `anyListOf` above, you can always specify generics explicitly using this syntax:

```
when(mock.process(Matchers.<List<Bar>>any(List.class)));
```

Java 8 newly allows type inference based on parameters, so if you're using Java 8, this may work as well:

```
when(mock.process(Matchers.any()));
```

Remember that neither `any()` nor `anyList()` will apply any checks, including type or null checks. In Mockito 2.x, `any(Foo.class)` was changed to mean "any `instanceof` Foo", but `any()` still means "any value including `null`".

NOTE: The above has switched to [ArgumentMatchers](https://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.7.21/org/mockito/ArgumentMatchers.html) in newer versions of Mockito, to avoid a name collision with `org.hamcrest.Matchers`. Older versions of Mockito will need to keep using `org.mockito.Matchers` as above.

Comment: ```Matchers.any()``` is very convenient!

Comment: Matchers is now deprecated, here's the info from mockito

"Use ArgumentMatchers. This class is now deprecated in order to avoid a name clash with Hamcrest org.hamcrest.Matchers class. This class will likely be removed in version 3.0."

https://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.7.21/org/mockito/Matchers.html

Comment: @oddmeter Changes made.

Answer (score 17):

Before Java 8 (versions 7 or 6) I use the new method ArgumentMatchers.anyList:

```
import static org.mockito.Mockito.*;
import org.mockito.ArgumentMatchers;

verify(mock, atLeastOnce()).process(ArgumentMatchers.<Bar>anyList());
```

Answer (score 3):

I needed `anyList()` with a typed ArrayList, the following worked:

```
(ArrayList<Bar>) ArgumentMatchers.<Bar>anyList()
```

Comment: works flawlessly