# Mockito method parameter matcher with generic in java

Tags: java, unit-testing, generics, mockito

My actual method signature is:

```
public List<T> readFileToMemory(FooFile fooFile, **Class<T> entityClass**) { }
```

and I am trying to mock this as:

```
when(mockObject.readFileToMemory(any(FooFile.class), 
         Matchers.any(Class<Bar>)).thenReturn(new ArrayList<Bar>())
```

but second argument doesn't compile. How to fix it?

I referred to the following answers but still no luck.

[Mockito: List Matchers with generics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10512374/mockito-list-matchers-with-generics)

[Mockito: Verifying with generic parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6175753/mockito-verifying-with-generic-parameters)

Answer (score 2):

Oh i fixed it as:

```
when(mockObject.readFileToMemory(any(FooFile.class), 
                                 Matchers.<Class<Bar>>any())).thenReturn(new ArrayList<Bar>())
```

Comment: Just a note for other people just finding this: `Matchers` is deprecated in favor of `ArgumentMatchers` now.

Answer (score 2):

You could also get it working with:

```
when(mockObject.readFileToMemory(any(FooFile.class), eq(Bar.class)))
                                .thenReturn(new ArrayList<Bar>());
```

Comment: No, this throws me error as "Wrong 2nd argument type, required: java.lang.Class<Bar>"